# Solve line integral using Green's theorem

Tags: line-integrals, greens-theorem

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kjk.png)

I am asked to solve
$$\oint_{\gamma}\left(\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}-y\right)dx+\left(\frac{y-x}{x^2+y^2}+x\right)dy$$
where $\gamma$ is closed curve $\mid x \mid +\mid y \mid = 1$ with counterclockwise orientation.

Using Green's theorem it equals:
$$\iint_{D}\left(\frac{-(x^2+y^2)+2x^2-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+1\right)-\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-2xy-2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-1\right)dA$$
Simplifying:
$$\iint_{D}2dA=2A=4$$
Where A is the area of the enclosed area by $\gamma$.

I've been told that the correct answer is $4-2\pi$. What went wrong in the above calculation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You need to show us your work before we can tell you what you did wrong.  If you need help with the formatting, here's a [tutorial]https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to show my work.

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can get-adjustable size parentheses (and brackets etc.) by using `\left` and and `\right`.  Look at how I edited your post.  I'll need a little time to reproduce your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, your calculations look right, but have you checked that the hypotheses of Green's theorem actually hold?  In particular, you need continuous first order partial derivatives throughout the region of integration, and I doubt that this is true at the origin.  It appears to me that the partial derivatives don't exist at $(0,0)$.

I think you have to do this one by computing the four line integrals directly.

**EDIT**

Actually, you can do this one with Green's theorem, but you have to take care.  For $0<r<1$, let $\sigma_r$ be the positively circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin, and let $D_r$ be the region inside the given square, but outside $\sigma_r$.  By Green's Theorem, $$\int_\gamma P\mathrm{d}x+Q\mathrm{d}y-\int_{\sigma_r} P\mathrm{d}x+Q\mathrm{d}y=\iint_{D_r}\left(Q_x-P_y\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{dy}\tag{1}$$ and your calculation is valid over $D_r$.

The integral of $\sigma_r$ is easily evaluated by switching to polar coordinates.  Now, if you let $r\to0+$, you'll get the integral over $\gamma$.  Give it a try!

Comment: Oh that's it! thank you so much for answering my question! Also thanks for the tip about parentheses!

Comment: My pleasure.  If the answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so it leaves the unanswered queue (and I get a little more rep :-)).

Comment: Thank you for your further clarification! I got $-2\pi$ for $\sigma_{r}$ part, now it all falls into place!

Comment: @Deemo Glad to help.

Comment: @Deemo Can be simplified slightly by taking the unit circle, then $\boldsymbol F = (x, y)$ is normal to the circle and your integral is $-2$ times the area between the square and the circle.